# Gitlab Pipeline takes more time when added new runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab pipeline for CI everything was working fine until adding a new runner from different machine . Removed the old runner & new runner were made active from that point the pipeline is taking more time to execute . Only change is gitlab version previous machine we used version=14.6.0 and new machine version=15.1.0.

Any idea what could be the reason for this ?

Comment: What is the underlying hardware being used on the two machines? are they the same or different? for example (and in very very rough terms) running a pipeline on a runner installed on an i5 might be slower than running the same job on a pipeline that is running on an i7.

Comment: Current machine config
processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x15
cpu MHz         : 1596.751
cache size      : 6144 KB
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
New machine 
processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 106
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6336Y CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 6
microcode       : 0xd000331
cpu MHz         : 2394.374
cache size      : 36864 KB
physical id     : 6

Comment: I think that kind of explains it - they have different hardware so I would expect the jobs time to be different when running on the other machine compared to the original.

Comment: what would be your suggestion to have a better configuration so pipeline takes lesser time ?

Comment: It would depend entirely on what you are trying to build and the requirements that it has to be sped up. For example if you were compiling C++ code you might be CPU bound, thus having a faster and more efficient CPU would give you an increase in speed and reduce the duration. However if it was something that could be run in parallel, then more cores would help by running things together at the same time. so there isn't a magic one way to speed things up without going for better hardware.

Comment: We use golang mostly . Mentioned above requirements would be fine for it ?